# HTML5 - Is there a way to highlight a specific day? (thought javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, datepicker

I'm working with HTML5 elements on my webpage. By default, on the click of the date picker icon, the current date is highlighted.

`<input id="dateField" type="date" name="date-field"/>`

[image]

How can I configure it to highlight a specific date instead of the current year? say 1st Jan of the current year?

I tried to do this
`document.getElementById('dateField').defaultValue = '2021-01-01'`

and
`<input id="dateField" type="date" name="date-field" value="2021-01-01"/>`

but this will not only highlights but also selects the date.

Comment: i think either you have to live with the fact that it selects the date or make a custom datefield picker that does not depend on the default browser UI

Answer (score 1):

You can use the value attribute like this:

```html
<input id="dateField" type="date" name="date-field" value="2017-06-01"/>
```

You can learn more about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#value).

Comment: This would set the value of this field to the specified date. Unfortunately, I just want this date to be just highlighted when the user opens the date picker.